# How to ignore other folders on Team checkin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

[Team Anywhere always scan other project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSQYk.png)

(Click the above link to see the screenshot)

I have an Android project under c:\AndroidDevelopment, with Team Anywhere installed so I can connect to TFS(visualstudio.com) and do source code control. However, whenever I try to check in a file, it takes a long time to come up with this check in window and I think the problem is, as you can see in the screenshot, it scans the whole world of C:\Projects. Why it scans C:\Projects folder? which has nothing to do with my android project under c:\AndroidDevelopment?
How to tell the Team Anywhere not to do that? (Or what causes TeamAnywhere to scan c:\projects folder?)

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your TFS workspace settings, best guess is your workspace includes C:\Projects\

Comment: Where can I find the TFS workspace settings? I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a local workspace, Eclipse can detect changes that you make outside the system.

If you make changes outside Eclipse to projects that are in your Eclipse workspace, refresh the Package Explorer or Project Explorer to see your changes. Changes will be detected automatically.

You can manage your workspace under Pending Changes--Actions to see whether you have mapped C:\Projects\ folder:

[image]

If items that you don’t need to check in are appearing regularly in the **Promote Candidate Changes** dialog box, you can select one of them, open its shortcut menu, and choose **Ignore this local item** to ignore the item.

You can also customize which files are ignored by version control. You can configure which kinds of files are ignored by placing text file called **.tfignore** in the folder where you want rules to apply. The effects of the .tfignore file are recursive. However, you can create .tfignore files in sub-folders to override the effects of a .tfignore file in a parent folder. More information, please check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155786(v=vs.120).aspx